# How can i fix this, my login page wont connect and i keep on getting this error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, background, ImageBackground,} from 'react-native';

import { navigate, navigation, } from 'react-navigation';

const lockIcon = require("./assets/images/lock.png");
const personIcon = require("./assets/images/person.png");


export default class screens extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        style={[styles.background, styles.container]} 
        source={background}
        resizeMode="cover"
      >
        <View style={styles.container} />
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
            <View style={styles.iconWrap}>
              <Image
                source={personIcon}
                style={styles.icon}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            </View>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Username"
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
            <View style={styles.iconWrap}>
              <Image
                source={lockIcon}
                style={styles.icon}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            </View>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Password"
              secureTextEntry
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            />
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} style={styles.button}
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
       onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
        />
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container} />
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITSz6.png)

Comment: Hi, I see that you are a new contributor. Can you add a bit of context to your question ?

Comment: I'm trying to connect my index.js page which is my login to my profile page which is also connected to my app.js which is my navigation page and everytime i try to navigate to a page it wont work

Comment: It looks like you meant to do `import navigation, { navigate }` instead of `import { navigation, navigate }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused with react-navigation API.

First, you need to understand one thing: you can not just make `import { navigation  } from 'react-navigation'` and then call `navigation.navigate('YourRoute')`, because the library (`react-navigation`) has no idea about your screens (routes). To make it understand what `YourRoute` (in your case it's `Profile`) actually is, you need to provide it some information.

Create separate file and call it `Navigation`. Then paste this code into it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import LoginScreen from './pathToYourLoginScreenGoesHere';
import ProfileScreen from './pathToYourProfileScreenGoesHere';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  },
);

export default AppNavigator;
```

By doing that, you create your basic navigation stack with two screens (Login and Profile) and have your `Login` screen as `initial`. But now it's just a separate file and your application knows nothing about it. Now you should connect this file with your app. Modify your `App.js` file:

```
import AppNavigator from './hereGoesRouteToThePreviousFile';

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

Providing `AppContainer` as a root component of your app you pass all necessary props to child screens. Now you have `navigation` prop in your child screens under the hood.

Now you should modify your file in 2 steps:

1. Delete `import { navigate, navigation, } from 'react-navigation';` string
2. Right before `return` word you should paste this line of code: `const { navigation } = this.props;`

So now your file should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground,} from 'react-native';

import styles from './pathToYourStylesFile';

const background = require("./assets/images/yourBackgroundImageFile.png");
const lockIcon = require("./assets/images/lock.png");
const personIcon = require("./assets/images/person.png");


export default class screens extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <ImageBackground
         style={[styles.background, styles.container]} 
         source={background}
         resizeMode="cover"
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
              <View style={styles.iconWrap}>
                <Image
                  source={personIcon}
                  style={styles.icon}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                />
              </View>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Username"
                style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
              <View style={styles.iconWrap}>
                <Image
                  source={lockIcon}
                  style={styles.icon}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                />
              </View>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} style={styles.button}
              title="Go to Jane's profile"
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        <View style={styles.container} />
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Also pay attention at these moments: I deleted import of `background` property from 'react-native' lib, because there is no exported property like that in react-native. Instead, provide real path to `const background = require("./assets/images/yourBackgroundImageFile.png");`, it should be a real image you want to use as a background image.

Comment: @user12493514 I'm glad it worked for you=) Happy coding!